# Making gtk's pkg-config --libs not include a newline on windows

Tags: windows, gtk, ocaml, gtksourceview, ocamlfind

I recently installed GTK from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.24/gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.zip.  The `pkg-config` installed from this seems to like appending `^M` to its lines, at least in some cases:

```
$ /cygdrive/d/opt/gtk/bin/pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs >foo; cat -v foo; rm foo
-LD:/opt/gtk/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl  ^M
```

This breaks the configure script of lablgtk2, which I need to build Coq from sources.  (Coq tests for `lablgtk2.sourceview2`, which the prebuilt Windows version of `lablgtk2` doesn't seem to include.

How do I get gtk+'s `pkg-config` to stop appending `^M` (or get `lablgtk2.sourceview2` some other way)?

Comment: I would recommend workarounding this in lablgtk2 build system - simple sed on pkg-config output should do it..

Comment: `pkg-config` outputs a newline (0x0A) on Linux too.